# Swift2 closure that throws

Tags: ios, macos, swift, swift2

I am trying to create a closure that can throw, and pass it as an argument to another function. For example:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

  /// The same as performBlockAndWait, except it can handle closures that throw.
  func performBlockAndWaitOrThrow(block: (() -> throws Void)) throws {
    // ...
    try block()
  }
}
```

Note that the |block| argument is a closure that can throw.

However, this doesn't compile. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `throws` keyword should come **before** the arrow. This compiles:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    /// The same as performBlockAndWait, except it can handle closures that throw.
    func performBlockAndWaitOrThrow(block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
        // ...
        try block()
    }
}
```

Comment: Derp, I've been staring at this code for too long. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything but run a throwing closure...?

Comment: The question was about the syntax for passing a throwing closure, so that is all the answer covers.